# How to match div content which has divs inside by using regex

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing

Content is

```
<html>...<div id="endText" class="end-text" jcid="8311"><p>Hello</p>World<div class="ep-source cDGray"></div></div>...</html>
```

How to match

```
<p>Hello</p>World<div class="ep-source cDGray"></div>
```

Thank you!

@Rizier123

```
$content = '';
if(preg_match('/"endText".+?>.+?(?=<div.+?class="ep-source cDGray">)/i', $html, $contents) &&
    preg_match('/(?<=>).+/i', $contents[0], $contentss))
{
    $content = iconv('GBK', 'UTF-8', $contentss[0]);
    return rtrim('OK' . "\t" . $content);
}
else
{
    return rtrim('SKIP' . "\t" . 'NO_CONTENT');
}
```

This method can be used temporary, can't solve the problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Show your code.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Cant you just use a CSS selector?

Comment: @Rizier123 Code have been shown. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: @Ash I want to implement a very very light-weighted spider

Comment: @BillWong oops typed too soon. Okay so what are you trying to do? Im still a bit confused

Comment: @Ash To extract code block of a large div which has divs inside from a html src

Answer (score 1):

Just match and remove the first-level div.

Regex (matches the opening div, saves its innards, and matches the last closing div):

```
/^<div id="endText"[^>]+>(.*?)<\/div>$/ism
```

PHP example:

```
preg_match('/^<div id="endText"[^>]+>(.*?)<\/div>$/ism', $html, $contents);
echo $contents[1];
// returns: <p>Hello</p>World<div class="ep-source cDGray"></div>
```

Adding the `id` attribute to the regex helps to specify that particular `div`

Comment: The content is a part of a html src. Maybe "^$" cannot solve it.

Comment: @BillWong You didn't specify that in your question. I'll make a small edit to my answer.

Comment: I edited my question.